# Email using couponRow AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, campaign

I have created a welcome email for customers.

There is a content that is the same for everyone, but there is a block that is not the same because there are times that there will be a coupon and others that not because they have finished. So I don't know how to prevent the coupon from being shown when there isn't.

The code is the following:

```
%%[
var @couponRow, @ucmid, @couponCode, 

set @email = AttributeValue("Email Address")
set @FirstName = AttributeValue("First Name")
set @LastName = AttributeValue("Last Name")
set @AssetNumber = AttributeValue("Asset Number")
SET @Eligible = AttributeValue("Eligible")

IF @Eligible = "true" THEN
set @couponRow = ClaimRow('test_DE','IsClaimed', 'Email Address', @email, 'First Name', @FirstName, 'Last Name', @LastName, 'Asset Number', @AssetNumber)

ENDIF

if @Eligible = "false" then
]%%

You shall not receive any codes today!

%%[
ELSE IF (@Eligible = "true" AND NOT empty(@couponRow)) THEN
]%%

Your code is %%=Field(@couponRow,'CouponCode')=%%

%%[
ELSE
RaiseError('No coupons available', false)
endif
]%%
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have managed to mess up the code when copy pasting my latest answer. You always need two (2) equal symbols (=) when doing comparison in Ampscript. Please refer to the documentation on [Ampscript Language Elements](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/languageElements.htm). Below is the code, cleaned up.

It is not mandatory to provide this many arguments to ClaimRow function, as these variables will not benefit you. You shall take a look at the [documentation here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/claimrow.htm). The main reason for providing e.g. jobID, is e.g. to ensure the same voucher code gets sent to the recipient in case of the email being viewed as a web page.

```
%%[
var @couponRow, @ucmid, @couponCode

set @email = AttributeValue("Email Address")
set @FirstName = AttributeValue("First Name")
set @LastName = AttributeValue("Last Name")
set @AssetNumber = AttributeValue("Asset Number")
SET @Eligible = AttributeValue("Eligible")

IF @Eligible == "true" THEN
set @couponRow = ClaimRow('test_DE', 'IsClaimed', 'JobID', JobID, 'ListID', ListID, 'BatchID', _JobSubscriberBatchID, 'SubscriberID', SubscriberID)

ENDIF

if @Eligible == "false" then
]%%

You shall not receive any codes today!

%%[
ELSE IF (@Eligible == "true" AND NOT empty(@couponRow)) THEN
]%%

Your code is %%=Field(@couponRow,'CouponCode')=%%

%%[
ELSE
RaiseError('No coupons available', false)
endif
]%%
```

Comment: Thanks, it's ok.